# When can document.documentElement be null?

Tags: javascript, dom, flowtype

I've come across a use case with Flow, and when I use `document.documentElement` I need to first type refine it because it has the possibility of being null as defined in their built in definitions.

https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/8391250177e37a047a33ae728fdbd1138632294a/lib/dom.js#L824

```
const { documentElement } = document;
if (documentElement instanceof HTMLElement) {
  // continue doing stuff
}
```

Doing a simple google does not yield any results for why this is the case. So my question is when can this value be null or is it a mistake from the lib defs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would assume it's coming directly from the spec's type definitions.  It's possible for `Document#documentElement` to be any element or no element in the case of an "empty document".  You can construct `Document`s, so there could be cases where it isn't an `HTMLElement`.  It seems a little contrived, but I think the types are supposed to account for all cases.  So if you have a **empty** document, it may fail.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement):

> For any non-empty HTML document, `documentElement` will always be an
> `<html>` element. For any non-empty XML document, `documentElement` will
> always be whatever element is the root element of the document.

```js
const d = new Document();
console.log(`document.documentElement: ${document.documentElement instanceof HTMLElement}`);
console.log(`d.documentElement: ${d.documentElement instanceof HTMLElement}`);
```